# Scipy.least_squares giving "ValueError: Residuals are not finite in the initial point." when the initial evaluation of the error function is finite

Tags: python, numpy, optimization, scipy-optimize, nonlinear-optimization

I am using the scipy.least_squares minimization algorithm to fit a complex model to some data. The model itself uses a forward Euler method to solve a differential equation, under a 3 different sets of initial conditions each of which correspond to a set of data which I am trying to fit. The error function calculates calculates the difference between the data and the simulation for each set of initial conditions and concatenates them. The goal is to optimise 4 parameters which are all positive. When I run the least squares algorithm it returns the error "ValueError: Residuals are not finite in the initial point.". However, my testing has shown that this is not the case.

For simplicity I will leave out the details of the model itself but I have a predefined function called errfunc which takes the array of parameters as it's first argument and the sets of t (time) and y data as additional arguments. This function returns a 1D array of residuals (model - data) which is made up of a concatenation of the residuals for each set of initial conditions. For running the optimization, my code looks a bit like this:

```
param = np.array([param1_init, param2_init, param3_init, param4_init])

result = least_squares(errfunc, param, bounds=(0,np.inf), args=(t_data1, y_data1, t_data2, y_data2, t_data3, y_data3))
```

As far as I understand it this error indicates that when first evaluating the value of the error function, some NaN or infinite values were returned. However, I know this isn't the case, when I run the error function myself at the initial point it returns a finite array such that

```
residual = errfunc(param, t_data1, y_data1, t_data2, y_data2, t_data3, y_data3)
print(np.all(np.isfinite(residual)))
```

returns True. I can also plot the residuals for the initial parameters which shows that they are reasonably small and have the expected shape, indicating that the model is working as designed.

```
plt.plot(residual)
```

returns:
[Plots of the residuals at the initial parameter values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8LZTC.png)

My question is whether there is anything I have not considered which could be returning this error?

For a very similar model to this the optimization is working perfectly. The only difference in the model is an additional term in the differential equation and an extra parameter to optimise. My only thought is that the very large and small parameter values may be playing a role. The additional parameter I have introduced has a very small positive value (typically around 1e-29) but as I have shown, values on this scale produce sensible results from the model. Could this be effecting the least squares algorithm and causing it to raise this error?

Comment: try debugging `least_squares`, make a breakpoint inside errfunc, maybe you will notice something astray

Comment: @dankal444 Thanks for the suggestion. Having tried this it seems that something in scipy.least_squares is changing my parameter initial values to make sure they are greater than or equal to 1e-10. With this parameter value the model is failing and returning NaNs ( this parameter should have value around 1e-29). I'll try changing the x_scale argument to least_squares and see if that fixes the issue.

Comment: maybe it has problems with floats precision. You could also try to change this parameter to log(parameter) and in the errfunc use exp() to get it back to your domain (only if it will not be 0, to avoid log(0)). You would need to adjust bounds

Comment: @dankal444 I think I have got it working now. I applied a linear scale to the parameters before they were passed to least_squares which I then undid in errfunc before passing the parameters to the model. As you suggested this could also have workd with logarithms. It seems that when a lower bound of 0 was in place least_squares requires the parameter to be >1e-10. Scaling using the x_scale argument in least_squares appeared to have no effect. Thanks for your suggestions!

Comment: Glad you have this solved! Consider posting answer to your own question with solution for others to see.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to the issue. When placing a lower bound of 0 on the parameter values it seems least_squares was changing the initial parameters given to the error function such that they were greater or equal to 1e-10. Hence, my model (which expected a much smaller parameter value) was not working correctly and returning non finite values.

Removing the bounds didn't fix this as then the error function would evaluate properly the first time, but for later iterations the it increased the value of the smallest parameter far too much, and the same error was raised.

To fix the problem I manually scaled the parameter up before passing it to least_squares, and undid the scaling in my error function before passing it to my model.

According to the Scipy documentation, the x_scale argument in least_squares perfoms this kind of scaling, but I found that using this method my parameter initial value was still being changed and the error was still being raised.